# sqljocky querying database synchronously

Tags: mysql, dart

I am trying to query a MySQL database synchronously with sqljocky. I have a `Load` class that runs the query and gets the data then imports the data into a `User` object. The problem I am having is the Future that runs the query is not returning in time to return the object to the calling method.

```dart
DataObject user = new DataObject();
user.Get(1234);
// I cannot do anything here because the returned object is null
user.somethingElse();

DataObject Get(String ID){
  return access.Load(this, ID);
}

// Runs query
Load(DataObject object, String ID){
  // Set up query
  String query = 'select * from users where ID = \'' + ID + '\'';
  // Run query
  var completer = new Completer.sync();
  pool.query(query).then((result) {
    result.listen((row) {
      // Import into object
      object.Import(row);
    }, onDone: () {
      completer.complete(object);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you want to do something like this (Note untested code):

```
Future<DBObject> load(DBObject object, String id) {
   var query = "select ... where id='$id'"; // Note: check for SQL injection.
   return pool.query(query)
    .then((result) => result.toList())
    .then((list) => list.forEach((row) => object.import(row)))
    .then((_) => object);
}
```

Have you read this [article](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/futures-and-error-handling/) about using Futures?

The key point is if a method is asynchronous, and the calling code needs to wait for it to complete, then it must return a Future object (or a Stream in some cases). There is no way in Dart to get a function to "block" waiting for an asynchronous result. Feel free to ask some more questions in the comments.

Comment: I'm obviously late to the party, but how do I test such a code? By the time Future completes, the test function has already returned.

Comment: Here's an example of async unit testing: https://github.com/dart-lang/test#asynchronous-tests