# sqljocky query - method not found

Tags: mysql, dart, dart-io, sqljocky

Trying to query mysql database with sqljocky. This query works fine in phpmyadmin and return 5 rows with fine data. In Dart i got exception:

```
Class '_ResultsImpl' has no instance method 'forEach'.
```

I made breakpoint in query callback. Result object public filds are empty:
[image]

Ping function works well, so connection to base is established.
[image]

Even if i query simple "show tables" query, it returns to me empty Results instance with no data.

Query code below:

```
var pool = new ConnectionPool(
        host: '127.0.0.1', port: 8889, 
        user: 'root', password: 'root', 
        db: 'lulzvideo', max: 5);


pool.query('select id, title from users')
    .then((results) {   
      results.forEach((row) {
        print('Name: ${row[0]}, email: ${row[1]}');
      });
    });
```

Comment: Your code worked for me, but if I put that code (slightly modified for my table) in a main it will not complete. So if I add:

*.then((_) => pool.close())*

before the last semicolon it works fine. Are you sure about the parameters to the connection (i.e. are you pointing to the db with the data you expect)?

I am using sqljocky-0.11.0

Answer (score 0):

```dart
result.listen((row) {
  // Import into object
  object.Import(row);
```

[sqljocky querying database synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411171)

Comment: I wonder, why, but result.rows is empty List. Code do not get to print line, it fails in forEach. `The null object does not have a getter 'length'.`

Comment: Result seems to be a stream - see linked answer for more code.